# I am having trouble with @EnableWebSecurity annotation. It turns red even though I have added its dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, data-annotations

Here is my .java file that shows the three errors all related with `spring-boot-starter-security`, I have added two dependencies one is

1. `<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>`
2. `<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId> <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId> <version>5.5.1</version>`

But I am still facing an error.

[image: My code]

Comment: Please do not post images of code/errors/data. Instead post the code/errors/data as text in a code block. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If you have 1 you don't need 2. Please don't post images, post some actual code and please inlucde the imports. Also add your dependencies you have in your pom or build file.